# How to know calling process's logon session LUID?

Tags: winapi

Using the WinObj utility, we can see there are many logon sessions on a Windows system, seen under `\Sessions\0\DosDevices`, something like `00000000-004e948e` which is called LUID by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378275(v=vs.85).aspx).

[image: WinObj DosDevices nodes]

I also know that [LogonSessions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/logonsessions.aspx) utility can show those information as well.

Then my question is, how does a logged-on user know which logon-session-id belongs to him currently? One indirect way I found is: Running code like

```
DefineDosDevice(DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH, "CHJLINK", "chjTarget");
```

and see which node has `CHJLINK` created.

Is there any more direct way to achieve that information? Some Windows API, or some command line utility?

Comment: https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2224373&seqNum=7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need open process token and query it [*TokenStatistics*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) and use *AuthenticationId* from [*TOKEN_STATISTICS*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379632(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.